# how to style two elements floated right in two rows in a row?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im stuck with a problem.
I'm working on a website and I want to style an input with a label to float on the right side and the label to stay on top of the input on that line but the elements are staying as showing in the picture below.

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlW7p.png)

this is what I've done so far:

```
<h2>Pacients Info</h2>
        <button className="addNewPacient" onClick={showModal}>Create</button>
        <button className="addNewPacient">Read</button>
        <button className="addNewPacient">Update</button>
        <button className="addNewPacient">Delete</button>

        <label for="rowsNo"><b>Rows no.</b></label>
        <input 
            type="number" 
            placeholder="Rows no"
            name="rowsNo"
            value="10000"
            onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
        />


label[for="rowsNo"],
input[name="rowsNo"] {
    float: right;
}

input[name="rowsNo"] {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you show us your code?

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: I've added the code.

Comment: You should look up flex box for CSS. Your website will look messed up with someone who has a different screen resolution or ratio. But, in essence, you have to wrap those two elements in a div. That div has to have a display: flex and adjust it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap the input and label inside some div container and add styles to it something like this

```
<div className="some-class-name">
  <label for="rowsNo"><b>Rows no.</b></label>
  <input 
      type="number" 
      placeholder="Rows no"
      name="rowsNo"
      value="10000"
      onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
  />
</div>
```

Update the CSS to

```
.some-class-name {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  float: right;
  min-width: 100px;
}

input[name="rowsNo"] {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Instead of using float will recommend to use flex property of CSS, it really makes like easier.
You can follow this link for an overview https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/